# Emerge conflict between mesa headers

Tags: gentoo, chromium-os

I keep getting conflicts between

x11-drivers/opengles-headers-0.0.1-r28:0::chromiumos

and mesa. As both are being provided by ChromiumOS not the custom overlay I'm building I have no idea why emerge conflicts are existing.

How do I cleanly remove files from chroot using cros_sdk chroot environment or gentoo emerge tools?

How do I decide if mesa headers should be kept or those provided by `opengles-headers` package?

This is for an ARM build.It's a serious time-killer deleting the chroot every time an error like this comes up. That seems to be the only way besides ignoring collisions to overcome. I've tried adding the package to `/overlays/{overlay}/profiles/base/package.mask`

Comment: What is the full atom (media-libs/mesa::gentoo), for mesa?

Comment: It says media-libs/mesa-17.1.0-r5 so I'm assuming it's the `::rpi` overlay mesa

Comment: Actually in packages.use it lists `media-libs/mesa egl gles1 gles2 shared-glapi -gbm`

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to delete the sdk simply because of blockers.  if they aren't resolved automatically, you can try removing the two packages and let the system reinstall them as needed.

e.g. run something like `emerge -C <blocking packages>` or `emerge-$BOARD ...`.

if your custom overlay is causing the blockage, and removing the packages doesn't help, you'll need to resolve it in your custom overlay.

Comment: I did try that, perhaps these (non-core) Gentoo packages have something wrong? The errors basically remained unless I tore down the in-progress build (chrome-os)